# binary search function does not reach the the end

Tags: java, search, binary

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {

private Scanner reader;

public GuessingGame() {
    // use only this scanner, othervise the tests do not work
    this.reader = new Scanner(System.in);
}

public void play(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
    instructions(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
    boolean isAboveAverage;
    int counter = -1;

    while (counter < howManyTimesHalvable(upperLimit - lowerLimit)) {
        isAboveAverage = isGreaterThan(average(lowerLimit, upperLimit));
        if (upperLimit == lowerLimit) {
            break;
        }
        if (isAboveAverage) {
            lowerLimit = average(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
        } else {
            upperLimit = average(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
        }
        counter++;
    }

    System.out.println("your number is " + upperLimit);
}

// implement here the methods isGreaterThan and average
public boolean isGreaterThan(int number) {
    boolean isGreater = false;
    boolean isCorrectAnswerGiven = false;

    while (!isCorrectAnswerGiven) {
        System.out.println("Is your number greater than " + (number) + "? (y/n)");
        String answer = reader.nextLine();

        if (answer.equals("yes") || answer.equals("y")) {
            isGreater = true;
            isCorrectAnswerGiven = true;
        } else if (answer.equals("no") || answer.equals("n")) {
            isCorrectAnswerGiven = true;
        }
    }

    return isGreater;
}

public int average(int upperLimit, int lowerLimit) {
    return (upperLimit + lowerLimit) / 2;
}

public int average2(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
    double res = (firstNumber + secondNumber) / 2.0;
    Math.round(res);
    //System.out.println(res);
    return (int) res;
}

public void instructions(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
    int maxQuestions = howManyTimesHalvable(upperLimit - lowerLimit);

    System.out.println("Think of a number between " + lowerLimit + "..." + upperLimit + ".");

    System.out.println("I promise you that I can guess the number you are thinking with " + maxQuestions + " questions.");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Next I'll present you a series of questions. Answer them honestly.");
    System.out.println("");
}

// a helper method:
public static int howManyTimesHalvable(int number) {
    // we create a base two logarithm  of the given value

    // Below we swap the base number to base two logarithms!
    return (int) (Math.log(number) / Math.log(2)) + 1;
 }
}
```

I have problems debugging this code. In this class, i'm supposed to implement a simple AI which guesses a number based on your answer on the question "is your number higher then " + a number. My problems are a. the code does never reach the end of the range given (so, with a range from 1 to 10, it never guesses 1 or 10) and b. is does not stop in time. Java often repeats a question multiple times, but the program should say the answer as soon as it could know it.

My fault obviously lies in the play-method (I included the whole class for completeness), I just don't know where. My program functions, so a typo or programming fault is not likely. I must do something wrong in my logic, but I don't know what. Does anybody know where the error lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your logic:

- You are calculating `howManyTimesHalvable` in every iteration. This doesn't make sense considering the incrementation of `counter`. The last possible value for it is always 1 which can be far lower than current `counter`.
- You are checking if upper and lower are the same immediately after asking a question without updating those values. Just move it to the end of the loop.
- Last thing is that you need to increment the average by 1 when updating the `lowerLimit`. If the answer to "Is your number greater than `X`" is yes, then the new `lowerLimit` can't be `X`.

Corrected method:

```
public void play(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
    instructions(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
    boolean isAboveAverage;
    int counter = howManyTimesHalvable(upperLimit - lowerLimit);
    while (counter > 0) {
        isAboveAverage = isGreaterThan(average(lowerLimit, upperLimit));
        if (isAboveAverage) {
            lowerLimit = average(lowerLimit, upperLimit)+1;
        } else {
            upperLimit = average(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
        }
        if (upperLimit == lowerLimit) {
            break;
        }
        counter--;
    }
    System.out.println("your number is " + upperLimit);
}
```